# Using Python: Extracting tables from postgres DB as CSV files and adding current date column to the CSV file

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, export-to-csv

I have 25 tables in a single Schema as part of my Postgres DB. I would like to extract these tables as CSV files. These tables doesn't have a current date column to it. so we would like to add cuurent date column to the CSV file.

Planning to do this in Python and the code will be executed in a ec2 instance.

One of the option i explored is COPY Command

Comment: please post a question to be answered and what code you have already written. alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You mentioned you explored COPY, but instead you are going to use Python - what made you decide that? Python is certainly an option, but what about COPY does not work for you?

Comment: @Nick: COPY command works perfectly fine for you. 
The reason why i decided to go for Python :

Comment: @Nick: COPY command works perfectly fine for you. 
The reason why i decided to go for Python : will write the  copy command in PSQL initially and need to do the following hence chose Python  
1. i have to add current date value to the csv file - MY CSV file doesn't have any date field so just to capture the current date i will have to add a column.  2. Need to rename the filename with current date (sample_currentdate.csv)

Please help me with these 2. I dont have Python experience

Comment: You dont need Python to do all if that